# Randomly selecting a link in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to select a random link from a page. I added an alert to see whether the element is present or not. The page gave 'a is displayed' alert but I am getting following error on eclipse: **Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**

Here's the code:

```
String tag = "a";
    boolean tagChk = driver.findElement(By.tagName(tag)).isDisplayed();

    if(tagChk == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tag +" is displayed");
        System.out.println(tag +" is displayed");
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag));
        WebElement randomElement = links.get(r.nextInt(links.size()));
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Random link clicked");
        randomElement.click();
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tag +" is not displayed");
```

I have already checked the most famous answers present for this questions and none of them seems to work.

Comment: Your doing a boolean check for ` driver.findElement(By.tagName(tag))`, which is completely different from `links.get(r.nextInt(links.size()))` So pasting or telling whats in `links` will be great!

Comment: Links is the WebElement list name. Please see the third line of code in IF statement

Answer (score 1):

When you check visibility of link element, you result applied only for first link element on the page.

```
boolean tagChk = driver.findElement(By.tagName(tag)).isDisplayed();
```

When you use findElements to get the links list, you'll get all the links (visible and not visible).

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag));
```

Thus it is very likely that the randomElement will not be visible.

Seems you should get list of visible links at first:

```
String tag = "a";

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tag));
    List<WebElement> visibleLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    for (WebElement link : links){
        if(link.isDisplayed())
            visibleLinks.add(link);
    }

    boolean tagChk = visibleLinks.size()>0;

    if(tagChk == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tag +" is displayed");
        System.out.println(tag +" is displayed");
        WebElement randomElement=visibleLinks.get(r.nextInt(visibleLinks.size()));
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Random link clicked");
        randomElement.click();
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tag +" is not displayed");
```

Comment: No error on console but it's not clicking any link.

Comment: Did the line `randomElement.click();` executed?
What do you expect after click?

You can add debug information about random element index.

`int randomIndex = r.nextInt(visibleLinks.size());`
`WebElement randomElement=visibleLinks.get(randomIndex);`
`System.out.println("Index of random element - " + randomIndex);`


After this try to find manually this element on the page in selenium IDE (or firebug) by xpath - "//a[randomIndex]", so you'll see the exact element. May be it overlapped by other element, but still visible..